# Useful recursion for A059715

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, recurrences

- Let
  $$
  R(n,q,m,k,z)=R(n-1,q+1,m,k,z)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}\binom{q+m}{j+k}z^{q-j}[z^j]R(n-1,j,m,k,z), \\
  R(0, q, m, k,z)=1
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n,0,m,k,z)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}T(n,j,m,k)z^j
  $$

I conjecture that
$$
T(n,j,m,k)=\sum\limits_{p=0}^{n-j-1}\binom{j+p+m}{p+k}T(n-j-1,p,m,k), \\
T(n,n,m,k)=1
$$

I also conjecute that

- $R(n,0,1,1,1)$ is [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108) (with offset $1$) i.e. Catalan numbers.
- $R(n,0,0,0,1)$ is [A287709](https://oeis.org/A287709) (with offset $2$) i.e. number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ such that every peak at level $y > 1$ is preceded by (at least) one peak at level $y-1$.
- $R(n,0,2,1,1)$ is [A059715](https://oeis.org/A059715) (with offset $1$) i.e. number of multi-directed animals on the triangular lattice.

Note that [A059715](https://oeis.org/A059715) has no simple formula, so this representation allows to simply compute it using $T(n,j,2,1)$.

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
R_upto(n, m, k)=my(v1, v2, v3, v4, z='z); v1=vector(n+1, i, z^(i-1)); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; v4=vector(n+1, i, vector(i, j, binomial(i+m-1, j+k-1))); for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q+1]=v1[q+2]+sum(j=0, q, v4[q+1][j+1]*z^(q-j)*polcoeff(v1[j+1], j))); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1]); v3=vector(n+1, i, Vecrev(v3[i])); 
T_upto(n, m, k)=my(v1, v2); v1=vector(n+1, i, vector(i, j, i==j)); v2=vector(n+1, i, vector(i, j, binomial(i+m-1, j+k-1))); for(i=1, n, for(j=0, i-1, v1[i+1][j+1]=sum(p=0, i-j-1, v2[j+p+1][p+1]*v1[i-j][p+1]))); v1
test1(n, m, k)=R_upto(n, m, k)==T_upto(n, m, k)
test2(n, m)=my(v1); v1=vector(n, i, R_upto(m, n, i)==T_upto(m, n, i))
```

---

**UPD1:** It looks like that if we change $\binom{q+m}{j+k}$ to $f(q,j)$ and also $\binom{j+p+m}{p+k}$ to $f(j+p,p)$ where $f(n,m)$ is any function, then conjecture given above is still holds.

---

Is there a way to prove it?